# Nested group table rows with CSS jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, html-table

I want to make multiple level table like:

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+---------+
| lv1 | lv2 | name  | date |    value|
+-----+-----+-------+------+---------+
| - lv1: 1                           |
|------------------------------------|
| -      lv2: 1                      |
|------------------------------------|
| 1    | 1  | John  |01/01 |    100.0|
+-----+-----+-------+------+---------+
| 1    | 1  | John  |01/01 |    100.0|
|------------------------------------|
| -      lv2: 2                      |
|------------------------------------|
| 1    | 2  | John  |01/01 |    100.0|
+-----+-----+-------+------+---------+
| + lv1: 2                           |
|------------------------------------|
| +      lv2: 1                      |
|------------------------------------|
| +      lv2: 2                      |
|------------------------------------|
| +      lv2: 3                      |
|------------------------------------|
| + lv1: 3                           |
|------------------------------------|
| + lv1: 4                           |
|------------------------------------|
```

Something like this.. I tried like this but I don't know if it is right approach:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>- Lv1:1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>   - Lv2:1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>     -Lv2:2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>+ Lv1:2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>   + Lv2:1</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>   + Lv2:2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>   + Lv2:3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>+ Lv1:3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>+ Lv1:4</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

even though I can make this fold/unfold with jQuery. Also let me mention that I want to create this table from JSON or array. Please tell me if this is right approach and how to generate this table from object / array..

Comment: why does it have to be a table ? tables are an easy way to display data and are typically used,  but when you start getting complex nested data types then you don't always have to stick with tables

Comment: You could always nest with empty `<tr>`s and `<td>`s instead of white space.

Comment: I was thinking about div-s but I thought that tables are natural way to do that ;)

Comment: @ my comment above, you can nest it like this http://jsfiddle.net/cj94tzsn/ and given what you're trying to build, a table wouldn't be a bad place to start unless you need some deep functionality or need to create something a little more responsive.

Comment: @Evan it is hard-impossible to make nested `<tr>` -s if I only could nest `<tbody>` it would be great... also to @Evan again.. this jsfiddle is not wat I am looking for.. I need to group rows in nested manner.. multilevel not only one... As I think more div-s are more obvious

Comment: On the contrary, tables are lightning fast - browsers don't have to recheck all their countless (actually 300 something...) CSS properties for overflow and line-wrapping for each cell and row like they have to do with other elements and table-like div styling. **Always use tables whenever possible (ALWAYS! No exceptions).** I use them for pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're looking for here is `colspan`

This will allow you to have varying widths for your `<tr>` elements.. to animate any of these though (sounds liek you m, you'll need a javascript/jquery solution

I've set up a fiddle here to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/wdwogvon/

Is this similar to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: OK, but if I even put more dull `<tr>` elements one below other so it looks as I draw it it doesn't group rows as div could

Comment: I'm unsure of your objective here.. What do you mean by group rows? Is the fiddle I provided doing what you would expect?

Comment: I need to nest several groups one into another.. this fiddle that you send can draw what I need but id doesn't group/nest them